# Big problema when use thymeleaf th:ref

Tags: thymeleaf

My th:ref don't generate a link.

```
<td><a th:ref="@{/inativar/{id}(id=${cliente.id})}">Inativar</a></td>
```

```
      <tr th:each="cliente : ${clientes}">
          <td th:text="${cliente.nome}"></td>
          <td th:text="${cliente.email}"></td>
          <td th:text="${cliente.tipo_utilizador}"></td>
          <td th:text="${cliente.data_criacao}"></td>
          <td><a th:ref="@{/inativar/{id}(id=${cliente.id})}">Inativar</a></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo it should be `th:href` instead of `th:ref`

```
<td><a th:href="@{/inativar/{id}(id=${cliente.id})}">Inativar</a></td>
```

Comment: Oh god!!
It's realy !!
Thanks a lot !!